# Use a script to export meetings in Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We want to change computer reservations systems (CRS) to use the room reservation offered by Microsoft Exchange Server.
We have exported meetings scheduled for the coming months from current CRS to a csv file.
Now we want to create these meetings in Exchange keeping the name of the creator, the room, the description, the date, the duration
and start time.
Is it possible in Powershell, C#, or another language, to automate the creation of meetings?
THANKS

We tried CalendarEvent from module exchange online powershell but this cmdlet is not recognized